# How to invoke generic function via Selector at runtime in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, generic-function

I'm trying to register a callback for an UI event at runtime like this.

```
func observeEvent(event: UIControlEvent){
    self.addTarget(self, action: "eventFired:", forControlEvents: event)
}

func eventFired<T>(sender: T){
    print("event fired!")
}
```

It crashes and say that it couldn't find the eventFired: at runtime.
Can you help to solve this?

Comment: Calling selectors is an Obj-C feature and methods with generics are invisible for Obj-C.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use generic functions as targets for the selector string literals. Why? The selectors contain no information about the argument *type* of their targets, only:

- The *name* of of the target for the selector (method name),
- and, (implicitly) *the number of arguments* for the target of the selector.

In so, Swift wont even allow non-generic functions with same name and same number of arguments to be used as targets for selectors, since there will be a conflict w.r.t. which target the selector should make use of.

---

E.g., consider the following (playground) example:

```
class Foo : UIView {
    var button = UIButton()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        button.addTarget(self, action: "eventFired:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func eventFired(sender: UIButton){
        print("event fired!")
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
foo.button.sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)
    /* event fired! */
```

This works as intended, but now try adding the following method to the `Foo` class:

```
class Foo : UIView { 

    // ...

    func eventFired(nothingToDoWithAButton: Int){
        print("another event fired!")
    }
}
```

The same example as above now yields an error, as the selector is in conflict as to which target method to call.

```
let foo = Foo()
foo.button.sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)
    /* error ... */
```

> error: method '`eventFired`' with Objective-C selector '`eventFired:`'
>   conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector ...

We finally note that if we change the above additional method into

```
class Foo : UIView { 

    // ...

    func eventFired(nothingToDoWithAButton: Int, someBool: Bool){
        print("another event fired!")
    }
}
```

Then the selector finds, as expected, its target `eventFired(:UIButton)` as it can differ between the two `eventFired` methods due to the difference in *number of arguments*.

---

From the above, it's obvious that selectors/selector literals, in their current form, are too primitive to be able to use, and identify, unequivocally, generic targets. The selectors would need to include target argument type knowledge to be able to differ between same-name/same-number-of-arguments targets.

Finally note that selectors, in their current form as string literals, will be deprecated in Swift 2.2, and removed in Swift 3.0, in favour of a new expression syntax `#selector`, see:

- [Referencing the Objective-C selector of a method](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md)

---

*(Edit addition w.r.t. OP:s comment below)*

You could try to mimic a somewhat generic selector target by letting the target catch various signals from reference types (`...(:AnyObject)`), and handle the event depending on which type that is wrapped in the `AnyObject` argument:

```
class Foo : UIView {
    var button = UIButton()
    var sw = UISwitch()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        button.addTarget(self, action: "eventFired:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        sw.addTarget(self, action: "eventFired:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func eventFired(sender: AnyObject){
        switch(sender) {
        case is UIButton: print("button event fired!")
        case is UISwitch: print("switch event fired!")
        case _: print("unknown event fired")
        }
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
foo.button.sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)
    /* button event fired! */
foo.sw.sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
    /* switch event fired! */
```

Comment: @TaiHo You could catch `AnyObject` type in your target, and handle the subsequent logic depending on the actual (reference) type being contained in the `AnyObject` "wrapper", see edit addition in my answer above.

Comment: That's a pain :(. I thought I can do like this:
    `self.addTarget(self, action: "eventFired:", forControlEvents: event)`  
    `func eventFired2(sender: UIControl){
        let className : String = sender.dynamicType.description()
        print(className)
        let classType = NSClassFromString(className) as! UIControl.Type
        print(classType)
        eventFired(sender as? classType)
    }`  

But it always says that classType is not a type. Damm...